# OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Cannot find required template

Tags: c++, resources, ogre, particles

I am trying to create a fire in Ogre. However I only get this InvalidParametersException. I have no idea why the template can't be found. Here is a part of the .log file:

`12:41:49: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Cannot find required template 'Examples/Smoke' in ParticleSystemManager::createSystem at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreParticleSystemManager.cpp (line 327)`

I've got the .particle file in "media/particle/smoke.particle". I've also already changed the resource.cfg file and added the particle path. This is how I try to create a particle system:

`Ogre::ParticleSystem *colExpl = mSceneMgr->createParticleSystem("smoke", "Examples/Smoke");`

Comment: Did you verify that the particle scripts as well as the referenced material scripts are loaded? There should be a matching entry in the Ogre.log for each of them.

Comment: the problem was the particle file itself, it wasn't declared as particle_system Exmaples/smoke {...}. and I also had to add it to the materials/skripts folder to work. thanks :)